# Did any East Asian scholars do any work on Buddhist logic and epistemology?

Tags: philosophy, mahayana, chinese-buddhism, dharmakirti

Did any Chinese, Japanese, Korean, or Vietnamese Buddhists write about Buddhist logic in the tradition of Vasubandhu, Dignaga, and Dharmakirti? What were their contributions to logic and epistemology?